# Oracle procedure out parameter returns -1 from PHP

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am trying to get Oracle procedures to execute from my PHP program. I created a simple test procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "JKJ3"."GetUserLogin"
{
    userlogin_in in varchar2,
    userid_out out numeric,
    pass_out out varchar2
}
IS 
BEGIN
    SELECT user_id, password
    INTO userid_out, pass_out
    FROM "JKJ3"."USERS"
    WHERE login = userlogin_in;
END;
```

I tested the procedure using Aqua Data Studio:

```
DECLARE
    userid_out number;
    password_out number;
BEGIN
    "JKJ3"."GetUserLogin"('UserName', userid_out, password_out);
    dbms_enable(10000);
    dbms_put_line(userid_out);
    dbms_put_line(password_out);
END;
```

This works fine, returns the userid and the password value.  So far so good!

I tried executing the procedure from PHP but I cant get the procedure to work to save my life!
PHP Code:

```
PutEnv("ORACLE_HOME=/afs/cad/solaris/oraclient10.2");   
$this->conn=oci_connect($this->ucid, $this->dbpassword, $this->db);

// Check if connection was sucessful.
if ( !$this->conn ) {
    echo "Unable to connect: " . var_dump( OCIError() );
    die("Unable to connect: " . var_dump( OCIError() ));
}

$query = 'BEGIN "JKJ3"."GetUserLogin"(:login_in, :userid_out, :password_out); END;';

// Execute stored procedure to add new user and return the new users ID        
$command = oci_parse($this->conn, $query) or die('Cannot parse query');

$userid;
$password_out;

// bind the input variables and out put variables.
oci_bind_by_name($command, ':login_in', $login, 30) or die('cannot bind login');        
oci_bind_by_name($command, ':userid_out', $userid) or die('cannot bind userid');
oci_bind_by_name($command, ':password_out', $password_out, 300) or die('cannot bind password');              

oci_execute($command);
echo 'userid = ' . $userid . ' password = ' . $password_out;
oci_close($this->conn);
```

When I execute this I get a userid and password of null.

**edit**
I have the same results with other procedures, heck I even went as far as to create a procedure that takes and assigns a static value to a return variable and I still get nothing back (including no errors).
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html (sayHello example). 
Once again the procedure works from Aqua Data Studio but not from PHP. No exception is thrown, no variable returned.

Does Oracle have something like the SQL SERVER Profiler that allows you to view queries being executed against Oracle?  (I dont have admin rights for the server though).

Doesnt seem like it could be permission based since it works from ADS.

I can run queries against the database without a problem so I am confident my connection is working.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with PHP, but according to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) page for oci_bind_by_name:

> You must specify maxlength when using an OUT bind so that PHP
>   allocates enough memory to hold the returned value.

Also, there's at least one minor syntax error in your PL/SQL block.  You need to always use double-quotes when referencing `GetUserLogin`.  (Although I doubt that's your main problem.  If it were, you should get an error message.)

Comment: Thanks, I missed that, however, I added the output lengths and its still not working. I have tried the PL/SQL block both with and without quotes, Upper case, Camel Case.

Comment: I also found that ocibindbyname (as well as ociexecute...etc) has been depreciated as of PHP 5.4.0. in favor of the oci_bind_by_name alias.  http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.ocibindbyname.php   Doesnt change anything but worth noting for future use.

Comment: The quotes should matter, unless PHP or OCI is doing something weird.  Do you have multiple versions of that procedure, one defined with quotes and one without?

Comment: I checked and only have a single version of each procedure.

Comment: I also find it odd that I never receive an error message, even changing to a stored procedure that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

After fighting with this it was a host of errors on my part (isnt it always?):

1. Not having quotes around procedure in PL/SQL block (and marked answer for the question).

   `$query = 'BEGIN "JKJ3"."GetUserLogin"(:login_in, :userid_out, :password_out); END;';`
2. Not having error reporting turned on (and seeing what the problems are).

`error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);`

1. Not having output sizes.
2. Passing the wrong variable in because I had the login and password variables transposed (*hangs head in shame*).